# Infinite Scroll calcular la altura de cada div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, scroll

Buenas soy algo nuevo con esta libreria [InfiniteScroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/), al momento de scrollar la pagina te va creando un nuevo article automaticamente hasta llegar al ultimo, lo que quisera es que cada que venga creado un nuevo article este vieniese ya con su altura calculada **class="article" max="???"** yo lo estuve intentando y todos me vienen con la misma altura ... si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

```
   <script>
        $('.article-feed').infiniteScroll({
          path: '.pagination__next',
          append: '.article',
          status: '.scroller-status',
          hideNav: '.pagination',
        });

            $('.article-feed').on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) 
                $('.article-feed').children(".article").each(function(){
                    $("article").attr("max", $("article[id^='article-']").height() );
                });
            });

     </script>

    <div class="article-feed">

      <article id="article-1" class="article" max="???">...</article>

      <article id="article-2" class="article" max="???">...</article>

      ... 

      <article id="article-50" class="article" max="???">...</article>



    </div>
```

Comment: No has intentado [.outerHeight()](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)?

Comment: No es tanto usar el .outerHeight() si no la liberia en si, que solo me calcula la primera altura de la pagina ya que las demas paginas vienen cargadas en metodo POST